# grab another children element on click GTM

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager

I have an HTML code like the below

```
  <div onclick="location.href='https://ford-parts-accessories.myshopify.com/products/ash-cup-coin-holder-with-lighter-element?refSrc=6748959244479&amp;nosto=productpage-nosto-1-fallback-nosto-1';" class="nosto-image-container img-0" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  
  <div class="nosto-product-info">
            <a title="Ash Cup Coin Holder - With Lighter Element" href="https://ford-parts-accessories.myshopify.com/products/ash-cup-coin-holder-with-lighter-element?refSrc=6748959244479&amp;nosto=productpage-nosto-1-fallback-nosto-1" class="nosto-product-brand">Ford</a>
            <a title="Ash Cup Coin Holder - With Lighter Element" href="https://ford-parts-accessories.myshopify.com/products/ash-cup-coin-holder-with-lighter-element?refSrc=6748959244479&amp;nosto=productpage-nosto-1-fallback-nosto-1" class="nosto-product-name">Ash Cup Coin Holder - With Lighter Element</a>
            <a title="Ash Cup Coin Holder - With Lighter Element" href="https://ford-parts-accessories.myshopify.com/products/ash-cup-coin-holder-with-lighter-element?refSrc=6748959244479&amp;nosto=productpage-nosto-1-fallback-nosto-1" class="nosto-product-price">
```

the click happens on the first element, both are children of the same parent, but I would like to grab the title attribute from the children below it. is it possible?

Comment: I think you are looking for a [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Comment: Please don't upload images of code instead of actual code. Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help on how to ask a question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a custom script variable where you have the power of JS and also have the {{Clicked Element}} object that you can then get the properties and parent of, and based on that, get the child you actually need.